# Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater (even though no dupes in data)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in skippedFiles.openCategories">
```

`{{skippedFiles.openCategories}}` prints:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Files with Code Differences",
    "description": "Customizedfiles in which the code is different between the instance record and  the platform record",
    "sys_id": "undefined"
  },
  {
    "name": "Files Deleted in  the Instance",
    "description": "Files which have been deleted by a developer or system administrator during thecustomization of out-of-box code",
    "sys_id": "49e13d4113b8e3442a393ac2e144b0e9"
  },
  {
    "name": "Files Deleted in Platform",
    "description": "Files which are no longer a part of a platform release, resulting in deletion of file",
    "sys_id": "6912358113b8e3442a393ac2e144b025"
  }
```

I have validated JSON and there are no dupes in it and yet angular throws Duplicate Key in Repeater.
I have tried `track by $index` but that does not help.

Comment: do you use any other `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong in your code, unless you paste the entire code here, would be difficult to answer.

I have created a code for you based on your question.

Have a look and let me know.

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        firstName: "Foo",
        lastName: "Bar"
    };
    $scope.skippedFiles = {};
    $scope.skippedFiles.openCategories = [
  {
    "name": "Files with Code Differences",
    "description": "Customizedfiles in which the code is different between the instance record and  the platform record",
    "sys_id": "undefined"
  },
  {
    "name": "Files Deleted in  the Instance",
    "description": "Files which have been deleted by a developer or system administrator during thecustomization of out-of-box code",
    "sys_id": "49e13d4113b8e3442a393ac2e144b0e9"
  },
  {
    "name": "FilesDeleted in Platform",
    "description": "Files which are no longer a part of a platform release, resulting in deletion of file",
    "sys_id": "6912358113b8e3442a393ac2e144b025"
  }
]    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in skippedFiles.openCategories">
    {{item.name}}
    {{item.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```